# Submitting posts from the front end - sanitizing data

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post

I have a form that allows any registered user to submit a post (it's a custom post type - forum related), and I'm using [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to insert it into the db.

From what I've seen in this function a sanitize_post() function is run automatically, but I think this only handles db escaping and such.

So how do I sanitize the input data the same way as the wp-admin editor does? I mean apply the kses filter and all the other stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a post is created/edited from the admin, edit_post() is called.

This function simply collects all the $_POST arguments and passes them to wp_update_post().

wp_update_post() then does some more logical checks and passes the data along to wp_insert_post().

wp_insert_post() calls sanitize_post(), which does all the heavy duty sanitization.

So, yes, wp_insert_post() *is* the correct way to do it.

Comment: but I still can submit any type of HTML, like `<script>` etc. so wp_filter_kses() is not applied to the post_content from wp_insert_post() ? In the admin it seems it is.

Comment: First, make sure the user you're logged-in as does not have the 'unfiltered_html' capability.

Comment: can editors post unfiltered html?

Comment: You can find out with a plugin, such as [Capability Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/)

Answer (score 2):

Otto did a blog about using kses last year, see if that helps.
http://ottopress.com/2010/wp-quickie-kses/